# Form post has "%10" written by user - json_decode() fails with urldecode()

Tags: php, json, ajax, jsondecoder

Was so awesome of the customer to type "**%10**" instead of "**10%**"

0_o

```
$PACKAGE_json_decode = json_decode(urldecode(($_POST['textarea']), true);

print_r($PACKAGE_json_decode); // LENGTH 0


foreach($PACKAGE_json_decode as $row){
}
```

**ERROR:
"Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"**

How do I urldecode without causing the %10 to take on a different meaning when sent back via AJAX?

And decode seems to produce that square character I cannot paste here... you know ... looks sorta like "[]"

*The string needs to be the same for the client when they get it back - they save it with a % they want it back with a %. 
- Any suggestions about replacing it?

Comment: Why do you need to urldecode when the data is not from a URL?

Comment: if GET? then?...

Comment: This isn’t GET so I don’t understand the question

Answer (score 0):

You could encode your request send by Ajax directly, such as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
```

Or like this:

```
JSON.stringify('%10');
```

Inside your PHP, just `json_decode()` now, as below.

```
$PACKAGE_json_decode = json_decode($_POST['textarea']);
```

Like this, your `%10` will become `"%10"`, et voila!!!

Comment: Why and how will this fix the issue? What’s the mechanism?

Comment: I refract my code as I thought about something better.

Comment: Since it’s already sent via AJAX according to the question, AJAX doesn’t change it into that, and urldecode will still mangle the %10, I don’t think that’s any better. I’d wait for the answer why they even need to decode something that’s not encoded in the first place.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen short example. Try `JSON.stringify('%10')` you will understand. You will get `"\"%10\""` and not `'%10'`

Comment: It’s not a single thing being sent from there, it’s inside other data. Again, let’s wait until they explain why they’re trying to do this before answering with hypotheticals.

Answer (score 0):

The % character is used in [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Either you remove % from the front end before passing to the server or you deal the same in the server side.

Comment: The string needs to be the same for the client when they get it back - they save it with a % they want it back with a %. 
- Any suggestions about replacing it?

Comment: Added one more answer below to share the code. Just provide more info where is it breaking ?

Comment: when returning from the database nd passing back with AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code and let me know where is it breacking ?

```
<?php

    $url_encode = urldecode("sampleTextWith%");
    echo '<b>Ecoded URL </b>'. $url_encode."<br>";

    $obj = new StdClass();
    $obj->text = $url_encode;

    $encoded_json = json_encode($obj);
    echo '<b>Encoded JSON </b>'. $encoded_json."<br>";

    $decoded_json = json_decode($encoded_json);

    echo "<b>Decoded JSON </b>";

    print_r($decoded_json);

    echo "<br>";

    foreach($decoded_json as $row){
        echo "<b>Row Value : </b>". $row."<br>";
    }

?>
```